# Does $S\leq T$ imply $\|S\|_{op}\leq \|T\|_{op}$?

Tags: functional-analysis, spectral-theory

Let $T:V\to V$ and $S:V\to V$ be bounded self adjoint operators on a complex Hilbert space $V$. Is it true that if $0\leq T-S$ then $\|S\|_{op}\leq \|T\|_{op}$ with respect to the operator norm? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general is false: consider $V= \mathbb{C}$ and $T  $ as the identity and $S(z) = -\lambda z $ for some fixed $\lambda>1$. Then $T-S = I+\lambda I$ that has positive eigenvalues $1+\lambda>0$ hence is definite positive but $||T|| = 1$ while $||S||=\lambda>1$.

It is true  if $S\geq0$ though.
In this case $T -S\geq 0$ implies that $q_T(x)=\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq q_S(x)=\langle Sx,x\rangle$ hence $\sup_{||x||= 1} q_T(x)\geq \sup_{||x||= 1} q_S(x) $ and $\inf_{||x||= 1} q_T(x)\geq \inf_{||x||= 1} q_S(x) $.

From spectral theory we know that $\sup_{||x||= 1} q_T(x) = \max \sigma(T)$  and $\inf_{||x||= 1} q_T(x) = \min \sigma(T)$
It follows that since $S\geq 0$ also $T\geq 0$.
Also we know  that the spectral radius $r_T = ||T||= \max |\sigma(T)| = \max \sigma(T)$  and $r_S = ||S|| = \max \sigma(S)$, it follows that
$||S||\leq ||T||$.

Comment: How did we use the positivity of $S$? Thanks.

Comment: It is used when I've written  $\max |\sigma(T)| = \max \sigma(T)$. (It cames from $S\geq 0\Rightarrow T\geq 0$ since $\min \sigma(T)\geq \min \sigma(S)\geq 0$)

Answer (score 3):

It is true when $0\leq T\leq S$.

By functional calculus on $C^*(1,S)$, we have 
$$S\leq \lVert S\rVert 1,$$
so $$0\leq T\leq \lVert S\rVert 1.$$
Again by functional calculus on $C^*(1,T)$,
$$\lVert T\rVert \leq \lVert S\rVert.$$

Comment: I do not know the meaning of the symbol 1. Could you explain it?

Comment: $1$ is the identity map.

Comment: I am sorry but what is $C^*(1,S)$? Thanks.

Comment: Have you learned about functional calculus?

Comment: Maybe you can check above inequations directly  using the definition of spectrum.

Comment: I know a little bit spectral theory. But I think I have not learned about functional calculus before. If you suggest some reference text-book for basics notions of functional calculus, I would be glad. By the way I have not studied on C^*-algebra before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/62309/discussion-between-c-ding-and-ergin-suer).